# External monitor with NO mouse cursor

Tags: monitor

I am using a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo L7310 laptop computer with an external monitor. I'm wishihg to use version 10.04.

The problem is, when I plug my laptop into the external monitor with my laptop screen turned either on or off, I do not see the mouse cursor on the external monitor!  The mouse cursor is still there, although invisible.   If I connect the external monitor to my laptop before swithing both on, the same happens.

Is there any solution to make the cursor appear on the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Is your system defaulting to just expanding your desktop to encompass the second monitor?  Try moving your mouse off the sides of the screen.  If the system is expanding your desktop to cover both screens, then its a matter of just moving your mouse over to the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

@Others: The graphics chipset in this is the UniChrome Pro IGP.

@Csaba: As a workaround, can you press Control+Alt+F1 (this should switch you to a terminal) and then press Control+Alt+F7 to switch back to the X session. I've seen a couple of reports that say this gets the mouse back.

I've also seen that Control+Alt+Left then Control+Alt+Right (should switch virtual desktops if you have more than one) fixes it for some people.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  Unfortunatley the keyboard combination does not work, I am still facing the problem.  No mouse cursor on the external monitor while it appears on the laptop's.  Is there any other solution to try?